# problems with CGAL AABB tree

Tags: cgal, aabb

I am using CGAL's AABB tree to perform point-location queries for my project. I have a cartesian grid in 3D and a surface immersed inside the grid. I need to find which elements of the grid are outside/inside/cut by the surface. For this, I cast a Ray and find the number of intersections for each corner of the cell and check if they are inside or outside.

This works fine as long as the corners of the grid do not coincide with nodes on the surface. But, I get rubbish results when the corner points of the cell coincide with nodes on the surface. One such scenario is shown in [Erroneous result from CGAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i5Vu.png).

I tried using `Simple_cartesian<double>` and `Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel` but the situation did not improve.

It seems that CGAL is so sensitive to floating point operations.

How can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code you wrote it is hard to say where the problem is. However the class [`Side_of_triangle_mesh`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/classCGAL_1_1Side__of__triangle__mesh.html) seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: I modified my code using the suggested Class. It is working as I need. Thank you.